# How to set font size property by using applypropertyvalue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to set font size by using applypropertyvalue in wpf

```
 ts.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty,new ?? );
```

Comment: @HighCore I want to set by using applyproperty

Comment: what for? is there any reason you're manipulating UI elements in procedural code in WPF, instead of XAML.

Comment: I am using rich text box. That's why i am using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
ts.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, (double)24);
```

or

```
ts.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, 24.0);
```

Either approach should work fine.